# Using Flexbox, how do you separate two items even after the row wraps?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Like the Title of this post, how do you separate two items even after the row wraps? I have a navigation bar with a logo (item 1) and Nav links (item 2). I want so when the screen shrinks the Nav links to go under and go to the right. Here is a [code pen](https://codepen.io/KuanaxBon/pen/RwVKoeo?editors=1100) and an example:

```
          From:
/**************************/
/*-item1-* *-----item2---* /
/**************************/
          to:
/**************************/
/*-item1-*                 /
/          *-----item2---* /
/**************************/


instead of 

         From:
/**************************/
/*-item1-* *-----item2---* /
/**************************/
          to:
/**************************/
/*-item1-*                 /
/*-----item2---*           /
/**************************/
```

Comment: margin-left:auto to item2

Comment: i don't know why your post was closed... the link provided under "already answered" does not sufficiently address your question

Comment: as Temani suggested apply `{ margin-left:auto; }` to the `<ul>` but you must also remove the `{ width:900px }` and remove "justify-content-between" from the `<nav>`